# Pipe message and auth login to a external script in Exim

Tags: linux, exim

I've been doing a bit of research but I'm stuck on this one.
I'd like to be able to get a message sent by an authenticated user and
pipe it to a script, along with the auth login of the sender. I'm
using plain authentication, and I've tried using $auth1-3 variables
but they don't work, if I try to print them they're empty. I'd like to
be able to do something like this:

```
[...]

begin transports

pipe_delivery:
  driver = pipe
  command = /bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/myscript $auth2"
```

Is it possible to do this with Exim? Any workarounds?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder whether at delivery time the auth user information is still available... once a message is accepted into the queue I suspect that info is no longer stored.

A workaround may be to include the auth user info in the Received: header line and then extract that info again in your script. My `received_header_text` definition includes this at the end:

```
 ${if def:authenticated_id {auth $authenticated_id}}
```